# Self join on table values repeating

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a query where i have to do self join to compare among company codes in one system.

```
select a.LIFNR LIFNR,b.LIFNR B_LIFNR,a.BUKRS BUKRS,b.BUKRS B_BUKRS,
       a.SPERR SPERR,b.SPERR B_SPERR
from Q45_LFB1 a
join Q45_LFB1 b
on a.LIFNR = b.LIFNR  and a.BUKRS <> b.BUKRS
and a.lifnr = '111000444';
```

OUTPUT:

```
LIFNR B_LIFNR BUKRS B_BUKRS SPERR B_SPERR
444    444    8810   1960     X 
444    444    2170   1960     X 
444    444    8810   2170     X     X
444    444    1960   2170           X
444    444    2170   8810     X     X
444    444    1960   8810           X
```

As seen in the output, 8810 is comparing with 1960 and again 1960 i comparing with 8810 which is not required. How to avoid that

Please guide :)

See image attached

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irmrf.png)

Thanks in advance ,
Vj

Comment: You should describe what you want to do, rather than giving  a non-working query.

Comment: Could you just specify your purpose? What's the purpose of your self-join?

Comment: @VijayVanamala You're probably after `and a.BUKRS < b.BUKRS` in your join condition, rather than `and a.BUKRS <> b.BUKRS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to output the rows where `a.BUKRS <> b.BUKRS` each once, then I would suggest use the condition `a.BUKRS > b.BUKRS`.

This is the simpliest solution you can use to find all `LIFNR` where the number of distinct 'BUKRS' is bigger than one

Comment: Thanks Emil, it helped me :)